# Validity of taking log of divergent sums in proof $\sum 1/p \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, euler-product

This short proof that $\sum 1/p \rightarrow \infty$ from this source, [pdf](http://www.warwickmaths.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/75_-The-Distribution-of-Prime-Numbers-and-the-Gaps-Between-Primes.pdf) the author takes logs of divergent series.

I have seen many comments saying that such proofs are invalid because you can't arbitrarily split and reorder divergent series.

**Question: I would like advice on why what the author has done is valid, if indeed it is?**

For easy reference, the following is a snapshot of the proof from the paper:

[image]

Comment: No, this is not valid. You can turn it into a valid proof by considering limits in an appropriate way, but as written this is not formally correct.

Comment: This is valid for non-negative series/products, thus convergent in $[0,\infty]$, equivalently writing everything as limits of increasing sequences. @Wojowu

Comment: Of course you can avoid anything like this simply  by assuming $\sum 1/p$ converges and obtaining that $-\sum \log(1-p)<\infty$ so that $\prod_p 1/(1-p^{-1})<\infty$ contradicting that it is greater than any partial sum of the harmonic series.

Comment: hi @reuns can you explain why this is valid for non-negative series/products? is there something I can read to better understand this? clearly this is non-trivial is someone as qualified as wojowu is wrong.

Comment: It is trivial. There is not much to explain, for series/products of non-negative terms you can expand and change the order of summation as you want without changing the limit. If the limit is $\infty$ then it will stay so.